I want to purchase same in-app subscription which is currently running on my Android
I've successfully added an offer in the Android in-app purchase subscription on play.google.com. The offer is for a Monthly subscription plan priced at £19.99, with a 7-day free trial period included.
Now, I want to give users a fixed amount when they are on their trial period. To do this, I created another offer with the eligibility criteria set to "Upgrade". This option gave me three new fields to fill out: Current subscription (set to Monthly), Existing billing period (set to Any), and Redemption cap (set to Unlimited).
I also added a phase with the fixed amount for users on their trial period. You can check out all the details in the attached image.
How it works can anyone help on this?
offer add details
phase add inside the offer
I've tried doing it with a bunch of different options, but the problem is I haven't bought the same subscription that I'm already on. And I really need to do that because I want to add a discount while the user is still on their trial period. It's just frustrating because I've tried so many different ways to make it work, but nothing seems to be clicking.
I have received error message "You're already on this subscription. If you want then please go (Manage subscription)". Which is taken me to the google play subscription.
